# Configure Netplan for Apache CloudStack

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I am following this tutorial on setting up CloudStack on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: https://rohityadav.cloud/blog/cloudstack-kvm/ there it says to configure your network like so:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
     enp2s0:
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp6: false
       optional: true
   bridges:
     cloudbr0:
       addresses: [192.168.1.10/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
       nameservers:
         addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8]
       interfaces: [enp2s0]
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp6: false
       parameters:
         stp: false
         forward-delay: 0
```

My Original configuration (50-cloudinit.yml) is setup like so:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [abc.def.95.26/20, 10.46.0.5/16]
      gateway4: abc.def.80.1
      optional: true
      match:
        macaddress: 72:5a:7a:a3:af:d0
      set-name: eth0
```

With this, working configuration, here's the output of `route` and `netstat -rn`:

```
root@cloudstack-ubuntu:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.46.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
abc.def.80.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
root@cloudstack-ubuntu:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         abc.def.80.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.46.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
abc.def.80.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

With the help of Netplan's man page and other sources (including the one above) I came up with this config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      match:
        macaddress: 72:5a:7a:a3:af:d0
      set-name: eth0

  bridges:
    cloudbr0:
     interfaces: [eth0]
     addresses: [abc.def.95.26/20, 10.46.0.5/16]
     gateway4: abc.def.80.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
       search: []
     dhcp4: false
     parameters:
       stp: false
       forward-delay: 0
```

With this config, same `netstat -rn` and `route` command output this, which to me should work:

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         abc.def.80.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 cloudbr0
10.46.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 cloudbr0
abc.def.80.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 cloudbr0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0

#route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 cloudbr0
10.46.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 cloudbr0
abc.def.80.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 cloudbr0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Yet I still don't have outbound connectivity. How should I write my interface and bridge's configurations?

My IP: abc.def.95.26, Gateway: abc.def.80.1, Netmask: 255.255.240.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you run `ifconfig`, what do you see with the original .yaml? My expectation is that your IP address is rendered as 10.46.0.5. Or are you even able to ping an outside address with the original .yaml file (as it looks strange to me).

I would try something along the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
  bridges:
    cloudbr0:
     interfaces: [eth0]
     addresses: [10.46.0.5/16]
     gateway4: 10.46.0.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
     dhcp4: false
     parameters:
       stp: false
       forward-delay: 0
```

For Ethernet, all that is really required is to set DHCP to false and optional to true; this allows for your new bridge config to set up the network and the optional setting will prevent Linux from waiting during boot for eth0 to fully activate (since it won't, as we're configured in the bridge).

From here I've made a best guess at your desired IP address and gateway. Not really sure how it would work with letters in it (though I'm no networking expert), as I don't believe IPv4 should allow for letters.

Once done, save the file and run:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Excellent first answer!  **+1** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1140791/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answerss in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for replying, the letters are just to hide the actual, public IP.